# Migrate from AMQP to Amazon SNS/SQS - need to understand concepts

Tags: rabbitmq, migration, amqp, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I am well experienced with the RabbitMQ and AMQP protocol, and have built a system with patterns for Commands, Requests and Events.

Now I am going to build a system running on AWS Lambda and therefore use SNS, SQS etc. I want to understand the "mapping" between these things.

What are the equivalent to an exchange in AMQP? What are the equivalent to a routing key?

How to set up queue bindings for fanout, direct and topic exchanges (or similar) in SNS and SQS?

How did other people handle this? To me it looks like RabbitMQ is a tool built to fit the usual needs of a message bus, where AWS provides blocks and you have to setup/build the functionality yourself. Am I right?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> What are the equivalent to an exchange in AMQP?

The closest concept might be SNS, as you can configure a SNS *topic* to publish to *n* SQS queues. Then when you write to that topic, each subscribed queue gets a message. You can also write messages directly to SQS queues if you like.

> What are the equivalent to a routing key?

There's no real equivalent for this. The SNS-to-SQS bindings don't allow for any additional filtering/control beyond topic-to-queue bindings. You could approximate routing by having multiple SNS topics i.e. each topic is a "routing key".

> How to set up queue bindings for fanout, direct and topic exchanges (or similar) in SNS and SQS?

- Fanout: write to SNS topic and every subscribed queue will receive the same message.
- Direct: write directly to SQS queue(s), or SNS topic that has only those queues subscribed.
- Topic: create SNS topic and subscribe queues accordingly.

> How did other people handle this?

I used RabbitMQ before AWS messaging, so I went through the same learning curve. AWS doesn't provide as many exchange/routing bells & whistles, but in my experience you can get *close enough* with some combination of SNS topics and SQS queues.

Comment: Thanks - your answer matches pretty good with my findings so far.

So basically, an SNS topic behaves like a fanout exchange in AMQP, from what I understand.

In my particular use case, I'd need this:

We have a couple of machines that does a job when they receive a messages (let's just say printers) and send a message when the job is done.

In AMQP I just had a Job.Start exchange and a routing key for each machine. Then I could log all Job.Start traffic in one service and let the machines receive messages with their routing key.

Comment: But in order to do the same here, I guess I will have to send to a SNS topic named job-start, with a subject that is the machine ID, and then have a Lambda that subscribes to that SNS topic, gets the message and dispatches a new message directly to the job-start-<MACHINE ID> - would that be a solution?

And what would you do about message-based RPC operations?

Comment: Its a bit late, but it might still help. I was faced with a similar issue where I needed to move away from rabbitMQ, and I chose to go SNS/SQS with Aws. It wasn't the easiest task, but in the end I put together a Symfony bundle to support my needs. Im not sure what framework you are using, but you are welcome to look at the project and adapt the code to fit your needs. Essentially the code is a big Pu/Sub that allows consumers(sqs) to subscribe to publishers (sns) which is how I manage my routing.
https://packagist.org/packages/beyerz/aws-queue-bundle

Comment: Just wanted to augment this excellent answer with an update, re: "the SNS-to-SQS bindings don't allow for any additional filtering/control" - as of August 2019, you can now attach a "Filter policy" to subscriptions which should allow one to approximate routing key behavior. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-filtering.html

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the AWS IoT service with its MQTT provides what I need in order to do routing rules similar to the ones RabbitMQ provides!

Comment: You'll have to implement custom queues though as AWS-IoT doesn't allow holding any data. It's more of a pub/sub system built over a MQTT broker

Comment: Aah - I can see that IoT does not persist messages...

But I guess I can subscribe SQS queues to the IoT broker then? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/sqs-rule.html

I guess I can rely on that the lamdas and other AWS subscribers will always receive the messages from the IoT broker, but external actors (like a machine or payment system) will need to create its own SQS queue and subscribe it to my IoT topic and then start to consume it, to avoid data loss?

Comment: @user2967920 I just made some tests, having a local MQTT client on two computers and connection to my AWS IoT based MQTT broker and subscribing and publishing. Even when I disconnected one of the computers, it would still receive the messages matching its subscription when I took it back online after a few minutes. So I guess there are some kind of buffer/queue present when subscribing to an MQTT topic on AWS. I was not able to see any significant difference in the behavior whether i was using QoS 0 or 1 though.

Comment: Are you using any SDKs for the Client? In terms of QoS, At most once (0)
At least once (1) Exactly once (2). Are you using thing shadow? How many mins apart were your disconnections and reconnections?